# Convert collection of system status timestamps into a timeseries

Tags: python, r, timestamp, time-series

I have a collection of timestamps relating to a system's state in a csv, like so:

[image]

Does anyone have a suggestion for the simplest way to turn this into a timeseries, with values between *pending* and *start* having a value of 0.5, *start* and *close* having a value of 1, and all other time periods (not between any *pending* and *close* timestamp) having a value of 0?

Need suggestions to use Python or R.

Comment: Think I got a solution, but would love to see others....

Comment: Please post your own answer below if you have it: others may contribute variations or improvement.